# ASP.NET Core Parameter not passed to Action Get Method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here, I have a Action method that saves data.

If the ID is null then it will return an empty object. 
If the ID has a value it will attempt to find the value int he database.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(string pID)
{
    if (pID == null)
        return View(new TestCaseViewModel());
    else 
        return View(await m_TestCaseManager.FindByID(pID));
}
```

In my javascript, I'm using [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) that generates the `href`:

```
var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": '/home/GetTestCases',
        "type": "get",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [{
            "data": "Name",
            "autoWidth": true
        },
        {
            "data": "Desc",
            "autoWidth": true
        },
        {
            "data": "IsActive",
            "autoWidth": true
        },
        {
            "data": "ID",
            "width": "50px",
            "render": function(pID) {
                return '<a class="popup" href="/home/save/pID=' + pID + '">Edit</a>';
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "ID",
            "width": "50px",
            "render": function(pID) {
                return '<a class="popup" href="/home/delete/pID=' + pID + '">Delete</a>';
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

[image]
[image]

However, even though the HTML see's the ID, the function never recieves it.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your last `/` by a `?` like this:

```
/home/save?pID=aksl09-12kjh8-198273
```

Comment: for sure. stack overflow restricts me from giving an answer right away. it makes me wait.  Marked as correct

Answer (score 0):

Your doing your link wrong.. it looks like you're doing a bad mixup of url parameter routing and regular GET parameters. You need to do either or, not the mix you have.

To do a real GET parameter, change your link to the following. Notice changing the final `/` to a `?` to denote GET parameters.

```
<a href="/home/save?pID=PIDHERE">Edit</a>
```

To do a url routing parameter you would need to edit your startup file and create the route when you add MVC. Something like this in the start up file.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{pid?}");              
});
```

then change your link to the following

```
<a href="/home/save/PIDHERE">Edit</a>
```